# generating ORM with hibernate in Java 9 application

Tags: java, hibernate, java-9

I'm trying to generate ORM using hibernate 
I'm using oracle 11g database 
and I'm getting this error after making hibernate code generation configuration

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field java.util.ArrayList jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.loaders accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @6a75c1c8
Unable to make field java.util.ArrayList jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.loaders accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @6a75c1c8
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field java.util.ArrayList jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.loaders accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @6a75c1c8
Unable to make field java.util.ArrayList jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.loaders accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @6a75c1c8
```

and this is my Hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">compte</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">compte</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">COMPTE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Could you update the question with the version of hibernate you are using(compatibility check) and the complete stack trace/steps that results in the above error?

Comment: when I tried with jdk 1.7 I got this error : org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Could not compute classpath
Could not compute classpath

Answer (score 1):

The exception seems justified if there is a type on your classpath which is trying to access the `jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath` which is used as an internal class in the JDK and is exported specifically to `java.desktop`, `java.instrument` and `java.logging` only.

A little more about [the unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module) :-

> The *unnamed module* reads every other module. Code in any type loaded
>   from the class path will thus be *able to access the exported types* of
>   all other readable modules, which by default will include all of the
>   *named*, *built-in platform modules*.

An alternate of accessing the package(in which the class resides) is by using the VM args ::

```
--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED
```

which would add a readability edge by opening the package `jdk.internal.loader` within the `java.base` module to all unnamed modules.

But ideally, a solution should be proposed/reached to move away from opening an internal package to access such a class which would be more clear when you look at the source of this error.

Comment: I can't understand this

Comment: @RiadhAzzouz `URLClassPath` is a JDK internal class not exposed for access outside JDK module and packages as listed in the answer.  Hence in order to need it, you might want to open the module to your unnamed modules on the classpath. Or else, depending on the functionality of which you were making use of, look for an alternative.